# GROUP BY IN SSAS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssas

I have the below MDX I want to adjust it to make member [SUM OF ACCOUNT] to sum all results in [Measures].[SALES_VALUE_INMKT_DETAILED] 
photo 1 is the current status 
photo 2 is the required result

```
 WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[SUM OF ACCOUNT] AS 
  SUM ([Measures].[SALES_VALUE_INMKT_DETAILED],[D ACCOUNT].[ACCOUNT ID].&[304891_1] )

 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[SALES_VALUE_INMKT_DETAILED],[Measures].[SUM OF ACCOUNT] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ([D ACCOUNT].[ACCOUNT ID].[ACCOUNT ID].ALLMEMBERS * [D EMPLOYEE MANAGER HISTORY].[EMP ID].[EMP ID].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
 ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [D ACCOUNT].[ACCOUNT ID].&[304891_1] } ) 
 ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [D EMPLOYEE MANAGER HISTORY].[MANAGER ID].&[10] } ) 
 ON COLUMNS FROM [Sandoz_Cube_DSV]))
  WHERE ( [D EMPLOYEE MANAGER HISTORY].[MANAGER ID].&[10] )
```

PHOTO 1
[image: PHOTO 1]

PHOTO 2 
[image: PHOTO 2]

Comment: Is this MySQL *or* SQL Server? Please take more care with your tagging.

Comment: sorry for mistake , you are right